# Embed image into Excel exported from lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a lightning component which displays the data from an object in table form. I am trying convert this table to image using `html2Canvas` JS library file.But in the exported excel I am getting this:

[image]

Here is the function in controller.js. This function gets triggered when a Button defined on lightning component is clicked.

```
  htmlToExcel: function(component, event, helper) {

 var container = document.getElementsByClassName("slds-m-around-large"); 

   html2canvas(container).then(canvas => {

    //canvas.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8';
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("slds-m-around-large");
    var css_html = '<style>td {border: 1.5pt solid #c0c0c0} .tRight { text-align:right} .tLeft { text-align:left} </style>';
    a.href = data_type + ',' +encodeURIComponent('<html><head>' + css_html + '</' + 'head><body>' +'<img src="' + canvasData + '">'+'</'+'body>'+'</'+'html>');
    //setting the file name
    a.download = 'exported_table' + '.xls';
    //triggering the function
    a.click();
 });
}
```

Comment: is the generated link valid?

Comment: Whats the contents of the cell in the excel file?